# Backbone web app architecture - best practice

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, web-applications

I am rewriting a web app in backboneJS and I'm wondering about the general architecture compared to my previous approach.

Please let me know if you think this questions should be on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of StackOverflow.

This is how I tried to build web apps MVC style without any framework like backbone or angular:

```
var App = function() {
    // ...
};
```

Every main object like `App`, `Page`, `Product` or whatever had it's own `model` property that holds data typically recieved from a RESTful API interface and a `view` property that holds a jQuery object with all HTML and event-handlers. It is cloned into the DOM once it's needed.

```
var Page = function(model) {
    this.model = model;
    this.view = this.render();
}

Page.prototype.render = function() {
    //get template, render it return jQuery object

    return $(html)
}


window.Shop = {
    app: new App({}),
    pages: {
        home: new Page({}),
        products: new Page({})
    }

}
```

This was my traditional approach to a lot of web apps. It was nicely structured and I always knew where to find my data and my views. More importantly they where part of the same object so I could easily handle my promises and/or deferred objects (hbs templates, API data, etc) between view and model data.

But with Backbone it seems like the `View` and the `Model` are their own, separate Objects and I'm not sure if I should handle the View as a child-object of the  Model, the other way around or even on the same level.

This is one approach

```
var PageView = Backbone.View.extend({});
var Page = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        this.view = new PageView();
    }

});

window.Shop = {
    pages: {
        home: new Page({}),
        products: new Page({})
    }

}
```

This is another approach where I see problems because I can't access the view from the model or the other way around (there is no relation between them).

```
var PageView = Backbone.View.extend({});
var Page = Backbone.Model.extend({});

window.Shop = {
    pages: {
        home: {
            view: new PageView({}),
            model: new Page({})
        },
        products: {
            view: new PageView({}),
            model: new Page({})
        }
    }

}
```

There are many other possibilities and I'm unsure what's the best way to move forward.

Comment: You may want to know about [Marionette.js](http://marionettejs.com/) for instance, which is a framework built on top of Backbone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the main principles of MVC is that models should never know about the controller/view layer. You should never access a view from a model. This is so that you can use the same model in multiple views.

In Backbone, you usually pass models into a view when they are created. Check out this following example.

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON());
    return this;
  }
}

var view = new UserView({model: new User()});
view.render();
```

Often this is done by fetching a collection from the server and then displaying each model in the collection.

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var UserCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: User
});

var UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON());
    return this;
  }
}

var UsersView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset sync', this.render);
  },

  render: function() {
    this.$el.empty();
    this.collection.each(function(user) {
      var view = new UserView({model: user});
      this.$el.append(view.render().el);
    }
    return this;
  }
}

var users = new UserCollection();
var view = new UsersView({collection: users});
users.fetch();
```

There are many tutorials out there that go more detail, you should check them out.